# Is there a way to store the path to the personal ado-directory in a macro?

Tags: stata

I know that I see the path to my personal ado-directory using the `personal`, `adopath` or `sysdir` commands. But none of these commands will return the path in a macro, as far as I can see. Is there some other way to save the path to my ado-directory to a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local path = c(sysdir_personal)`

You can type `creturn list` to see all system parameters and settings that are stored in c()